# How to determine top most object in 2d projection of 3d object?

Tags: algorithm, 2d, 3d

I have a surface to which a set of 3d objects is drawn. The task is to determine an object by the given coordinates on the surface.

For example: some objects are drawn on the desktop application, I need to determine on which object user clicked.

Could you please advise, how such task is usually resolved? Am I need to create remember a top-most object for each pixel? I don't think it is the best approach.

Any thoughts are welcome!

Thanks!

Comment: You may include a diagram ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name for this task is **picking** (which ought to help you Google for more help on it). There are two main approaches:

1. **Ray-casting**: find the line that starts at the camera position and passes through the surface point you are interested in. (The line "under the mouse", or "under your finger" for a touch screen.) Depending on which 3D system you are using, there may be an API call to generate this line: for example [`Camera.ViewportPointToRay`](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/Camera.ViewportPointToRay.html) in Unity3D, or you may have to generate it yourself by inverting the camera transform. Find all the points of intersection between this line and the objects in your scene. Which of these points is closest to the near plane of the camera? You can use [space partitioning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_partitioning) to speed this up.
2. **Rendering**: do an extra render pass, in which instead of writing textures to the frame buffer, you record which objects were drawn. You don't do the render pass for the whole screen, you just do it for the area (e.g. the pixel) you are interested in. (This is `GL_SELECT` mode in OpenGL: see the [Picking Tutorial](http://gpwiki.org/index.php/OpenGL%3aTutorials%3aPicking) for details.)

Answer (score 1):

If you've described the surface somehow in 3D space, then the ray, defined by your point of observation and a 3D point that is a solution for where you clicked, should intersect one or more objects in your world, if indeed you clicked on one of them.

Given the equations for the surfaces of the objects, you can determine where this ray intersects the objects, if at all, since you also know the equation for the ray in the same coordinate system.

The object that has the closest intersection point to your point of observation (assuming you're looking at the objects from above) is the winner.